# webRequest.GetRequestStream throws exception when calling from AP.Net Webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I need to call a third party legacy service with XML payload as a POST request from Asp.net Web API but I get an exception, it works fine from Console program. Any idea how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Exception on execution of code line
Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream() in the SubmitRequest(): 
**The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.** 
Inner Exception: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

To test this I just called the SubmitRequest() private method from Home\Index action with a valid url on line WebRequest.Create.

I have put a fake url (https://test.legacy3rdparty.com/API/API.aspx) instead of real one here in the question. But it is "https" url.

```
private static void SubmitRequest(string request)
{
byte[] dataToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);

// Change the following URL to point to production instead of integration
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://test.legacy3rdparty.com/API/API.aspx");
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentLength = dataToSend.Length;
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
try
{
    Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream(); //THIS LINE CAUSES THE EXCEPTION
    dataStream.Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    string response = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        WebResponse apiResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();


        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(apiResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            response += sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = wex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        using (Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            response = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    throw;
}
// Call Parse Function for the XML response
//ParseResponse(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This had to do with TLS handshaking. So when I updated the .net run time target framework in the in Web.config file to 4.6 it worked.

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
</system.web>
```